# WSSTRACING.EXE High CPU

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I've got a SharePoint 2013 Enterprise Server running on Windows Server 2008 R2

Its CPU load goes high and stays up, the process causing the high cpu usage is `wsstracing.exe`.

checking the logs using ULS viewer I see this error multiple times though out the day

```
Trace Service encountered an unexpected exception when processing usage event.
Detail exception message: Create store file error.. Win32 error code=5.
```

no more details on the error except error code 5 which I guess it's access denied

any ideas what the problem could be? what I'm thinking is that the service is running under `LOCAL SERVICE`, so maybe I have to change it to the farm account or the sharepoint services account?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Win32 error 5 is an authentication issue, http://www.mathemainzel.info/files/w32errcodes.html. Simply put the account running the tracing service doesn't have the rights to some of your log files.

Give access to the log directory or change the account of the service.

[image]

Comment: This answer could be very useful at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also check this answer: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/241668/50247